# How to detect multiple clicks and finally fire only one Update in android application

Tags: java, android, timer, android-asynctask

I'm implementing a MediaPlayer for Android at the moment using ContentProviders.

What I want to do is implementing a Listener for the "Next"-button that collects multiple Clicks performed in a specific timeframe and finally firing one Update-Query containing the information of how many tracks to be skipped.

For example in a 250 ms timeframe the button gets clicked 5 times then 5 tracks should be skipped. If it is pressed only once afterwards only one track should be skipped. Also the timeframe should not end after a specific time but be some kind of restarted on every click so that you have the possibility to skip so to speak unlimited amount of tracks and the update will only fire once the timeout is reached AFTER the last clickevent.

I tried multiple implementations but did not succeed to do so until now, and the only things I find in Google is how to AVOID rapid multiple touch events. But that's the point, I intentionally want them to be performed. Any Ideas?

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far. This is not a "me vision, but no idea; please do the work for me" service. I think what is needed is a (rather) complicated component that gets notified about these events; and does some "time window management" and makes decisions about that. But as said: *you* should come up with some code; then we might be able to help better.

Comment: The idea of the timer is good, just try to reset the timer every time the user clicks the `next` button, if the timer reaches the max value, trigger the `skip X tracks` action. You need some `AsynkTasks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ClickHandler implements Runnable {

        private static final long WAIT_DELAY = 250;

        private int count = 1;
        private long lastSubmitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSubmitTime <= WAIT_DELAY) {
                // idle
                Thread.yield();
            }
            MyActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run(){
                    // fire event for counter
                    System.out.println("Count: " + count);
                }

            });

            // reset reference so we can start at 0
            handler = null;
        }

        public void recordNewClick(){
            count++;
            lastSubmitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

    }
```

Then for your button event handling:

Declare the handler instance for that specific button somewhere:

```
private ClickHandler handler;
```

and forward the click-events on that button to your custom handler:

```
public void onButtonPressed(){
        // on input event from your ui component
        if(handler == null) {
            handler = new ClickHandler();
            new Thread(handler).start();
        } else {
            handler.recordNewClick();
        }
    }
```

## Note:

You could also avoid creating a new `Thread` every time, an reuse the existing `ClickHandler` and just reset it to 0, and wait until at least one click is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment a counter variable and send an empty message to a `Handler`.

Every time a click is detected:

1. increment counter
2. remove pending messages from the `Handler`
3. send an empty message to the `Handler` with your delay.

Once a message arrives into your `handleMessage(Message msg)` use the counter value as you wish and after that reset it to zero.